# Query to calculate difference between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I launch this query, but don't understand why does nor return correct result:

> 

```
SELECT fchalta,fchdevoluc,date_format(now(),"%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s") AS ACTUAL,date_format(now(),"%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s")-fchalta AS DIFERENCIA from tabla1

fchalta         fchdevoluc      ACTUAL          DIFERENCIA  
03/01/2022 00:00    12/01/2022 15:37    03/11/2022 10:11:50     0
03/01/2022 00:00    20/01/2022 10:05    03/11/2022 10:11:50     0
03/01/2022 00:00    24/02/2022 11:10    03/11/2022 10:11:50     0
03/01/2022 00:00    09/03/2022 12:04    03/11/2022 10:11:50     0
03/01/2022 00:00    10/01/2022 13:48    03/11/2022 10:11:50     0
03/01/2022 00:00    11/01/2022 12:55    03/11/2022 10:11:50     0
04/01/2022 00:00    13/01/2022 12:36    03/11/2022 10:11:50     -1
04/01/2022 00:00    23/01/2022 22:35    03/11/2022 10:11:50     -1
04/01/2022 00:00    28/01/2022 12:19    03/11/2022 10:11:50     -1
```

If i launch only this:

> 

```
SELECT fchalta,fchdevoluc,fchalta-fchdevoluc AS DIFERENCIA from tabla1
fchalta         fchdevoluc      DIFERENCIA  
03/01/2022 00:00    12/01/2022 15:37    -9
03/01/2022 00:00    20/01/2022 10:05    -17
03/01/2022 00:00    24/02/2022 11:10    -21
03/01/2022 00:00    09/03/2022 12:04    -6
03/01/2022 00:00    10/01/2022 13:48    -7
03/01/2022 00:00    11/01/2022 12:55    -8
03/01/2022 00:00    19/01/2022 10:26    -16
03/01/2022 00:00    11/01/2022 16:29    -8
```

Both, fchalta and fchdevoluc are varchar fields. What i'm trying is calculate days between fchdevoluc and fchalta. If fchdevoluc is empty, it must take the actual date and hour.

I launch this to see value where fchdevoluc is '':

> 

```
select (CASE WHEN fchdevoluc='' THEN date_format(now(),"%d/%m/%Y %h:%m") ELSE fchdevoluc END) AS FECHADEVOLUC
 from tabla1

FECHADEVOLUC    
12/01/2022 15:37
20/01/2022 10:05
24/02/2022 11:10
09/03/2022 12:04
10/01/2022 13:48
11/01/2022 12:55
19/01/2022 10:26
11/01/2022 16:29
03/11/2022 11:11
```

Last register has fchdevoluc ='' and take now date.

How can obtain days between both dates? I've tried many cases, but in ones retuens NULL and in others returns the year.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: *fchalta and fchdevoluc are varchar fields* For date operations they must be converted to dates using STR_TO_DATE. Then you may calculate the difference with DATEDIFF(). But the best way is to alter the structure and to store the values as DATE/DATETIME.

Comment: PS. Always investigate `SHOW WARNINGS;` output.

Comment: You **cannot** substract dates!!! they are converted to numbers (see DATE Literals in RM). Use DATEDIFF() as I have told above.

Comment: Hi @Akina, first of all thanks. I've tried this: 
```SELECT fchalta,fchdevoluc,str_to_date(fchdevoluc,"%d/%m/%y")-str_to_date(fchalta,"%d/%m/%y") AS DIFERENCIA FROM tabla1``` and result is ok:

```
fchalta fchdevoluc DIFERENCIA  

04/01/2022 00:00  14/01/2022 10:32  10
05/01/2022 00:00  05/01/2022 15:14  0
11/01/2022 00:00     -20200111
```
How can i use CASE or how take date now in last record where fchdevoluc is ''?
Thanks again

Comment: *and result is ok* Test for 2 dates with different month...

Comment: Hi again, sorry but i'm lost and beginner. I se what you mean, but if fchdevoluc='', how can i use current date instead '' value? Can you put an example please?

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(str_to_date(fchdevoluc,"%d/%m/%y"),str_to_date(fchalta,"%d/%m/%y")) AS DIFERENCIA FROM `tabla1` works equal if don't use datediff. Trouble is when fchdevoluc has no value, is ''. Then, return NULL for this row. How in this case instead '' value pt now() value?

Comment: *but if fchdevoluc='', how can i use current date instead '' value?* Empty string or NULL? *works equal if don't use datediff* Try not 04/01/2022 and 05/01/2022 but 31/01/2022 and 01/02/2022 - and you'll see the difference.

Comment: fchdevoluc can be ''
Ok, you're right, sorry.
But i don't see how solved when fchdevoluc='' it takes now() as value for calculate in all rows, with date and '' in fchdevoluc and always returns a number of days. I've tested many querys with CASE but i'm not on the way. Help with the query, please.

Comment: `COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(fchdevoluc,"%d/%m/%Y"), CURRENT_DATE)` instead of single `STR_TO_DATE(fchdevoluc,"%d/%m/%Y")`. PS. `%y` in the pattern means 2-digit year which will cause incorrect date recognition rather than `%Y`.

Comment: Hi again, i tried this:
```
SELECT fchalta, (CASE WHEN fchdevoluc='' THEN str_to_date(date_format(now(),"%d/%m/%y"),"%d/%m/%y") ELSE fchdevoluc END) AS FILLEMPTIESWITHNOW ,str_to_date(fchdevoluc,"%d/%m/%y")-str_to_date(fchalta,"%d/%m/%y") AS DIFERENCIA FROM tabla1;
```
but returns:
fchalta                 FILLEMPTIESWITHNOW DIFERENCIA 
11/01/2022 00:00  12/01/2022 14:29                       1
11/01/2022 00:00  2022-11-03                    -20200111

Comment: SELECT fchalta,
(CASE WHEN fchdevoluc=''
THEN COALESCE(str_to_date(fchdevoluc,"%d/%m/%Y"),CURRENT_DATE)
ELSE fchdevoluc END) AS FILLEMPTIESWITHNOW,
str_to_date(fchdevoluc,"%d/%m/%Y")-str_to_date(fchalta,"%d/%m/%Y")
AS DIFERENCIA FROM tabla1;

Same result and not return correct number of days:
 fchalta                 FILLEMPTIESWITHNOW DIFERENCIA  
03/01/2022 00:00  12/01/2022 15:37  9=====>OK
03/01/2022 00:00  20/01/2022 10:05  17====>OK
03/01/2022 00:00  24/02/2022 11:10  121===>BAD
11/01/2022 00:00  12/01/2022 14:29  1====>OK
11/01/2022 00:00  0000-00-00         -20220111===>?

Comment: @Akina, thanks! Just working!